# Find function which maps 2 function to 1

Tags: functions

Given functions $a$ and $b$ ; $a,b: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

find a set of functions $F$ so that

$f \in F \Rightarrow \forall t \in \mathbb{R} . f(a(t),b(t)) = 1$

does this set always have elements for every $a$ and $b$?

Is there only 1?

If there are more than 1 is there a pattern?

Comment: $f(x,y)=1$ is a trivial function with that property for any $a,b$

Comment: This question is very broad, probably too broad based on the MSE guidelines.